# jQuery: how to make an array with a loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to create an array in jQuery, which is filled through a loop.

```
count = jQuery('#count_images').val();
```

With the above code I get an integer value (such as 5, for example).
What I would like to know, is how I can do something like this in jQuery:

```
int arrLength = count;
string[] arr1 = new string[arrLength];
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++){
    arr1[i] = i;
}
```

So in the end my array for example 5 would look like this: `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: did you try looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I did, but that was not what I was looking for though. Anyways, I used dknaack's solution, and that works fine for me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Description

This is more about javascript and not jquery.
Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Mv6mX/)

#### Sample

```
var arrLength = 5;
var arr1 = [];
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i != arrLength; i++){
  arr1.push(i)
}

alert(arr1.length)
```

#### More Information

- [JavaScript Array Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptarray.php)
  ​

Answer (score 0):

firstly, `val()` will return a string, so parse it to an integer

```
var count = parseInt(jQuery('#count_images').val(),10);
```

Then you can simply use a loop  to create your array:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
   arr.push(i);
}
```

This would create an array with values `[0,1,2,3,4]`, if you want it to start at 1 just add 1 to the `i`

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
   arr.push(i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice:

```
var my_array = [];
var count = 5;      // let's assume 5

for(var i=0; i < count; i++) {
    my_array.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no special way for this in jQuery. It's the simpliest way:

```
arr1 = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) arr1[i] = i + 1;
// arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var days = $.map(new Array(31), function(item, index){return index+1;});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".chk-individual-vendor").each(function() {
    var arrVendors = [];
    arrVendors.push($(this).attr('vendor-user-id'));    
});
```